# Rails 4: Why a table in a generated PDF is not showing all the rows and cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I have an app in Rails 4 which generate PDFs. Those PDFs are reports which contain tables and other information. The Tables are dynamically generated in a view in the app and then when a user presses a button report, its export the PDf. My problem is that the table is looking not complete. I need to show all the information on that table, but only the first row is showed. Look at the screenshot image [image: Soa Table with missing row/s]

From the image, I see only first row complete but I need also the second row or next rows with the ticks. The ticks are added or removed from the app, that's mean the cell without the tick is empty. 
I'm trying to resolve this issue from a while but no luck.

the codes related to this table below:

From Controller:

```
def export_acrf
    html = ""
    html += "<br>"
    html += params[:table_data].gsub('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>', '&#10004;') if params[:table_data].present?
    html += "</td></tr></tbody></table>"
    html += PdfReport.page_break
    study_version = StudyVersion.find(params[:id])
    study = Study.find(study_version.study_id)
    lock = Token.obtain("#{study.identifier}_ACRF", "", current_user)
    forms = Form.where(study_version_id: study_version.id).order('ordinal asc')
    forms.each do |form|
      html += PdfReport.page_break
      html += Mdr.form_to_html_annotations(form.form_id, form.form_namespace, true).html_safe
    end
    #pdf = PdfReport.create("Annotated CRF", "#{study.label}", current_user, html)
    header_html = view_context.render 'shared/report.html.erb'
    pdf = PdfReport.create("Case Report Form", "#{study.label}", current_user, html, header_html)
    send_data pdf, filename: "#{study.identifier}_aCRF.pdf", type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline'
    lock.release
  end
```

The class:

```
class PdfReport

  C_CLASS_NAME = "PdfReport"

  def self.create(title, sub_title, user, body_html, header_html)
    paper_size = "A4"
    html = page_header(header_html)
    html += title_page(title, sub_title, user)
    # Document history
    html += body_html
    # Completion instructions
    html += page_footer()
    ConsoleLogger.log(C_CLASS_NAME, "create", "HTML=" + html.to_s)
    # pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html, :page_size => paper_size, :footer => {:font_size => "10", :font_name => "Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif", :left => "", :center => "", :right => "[page] of [topage]"} )
    options = { :page_size => paper_size, :footer => {:font_size => "10", :font_name => "Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif", :left => "", :center => "", :right => "[page] of [topage]"} }
    pdf = CdiscChangesReport.export(html, options)
    return pdf
  end

  def self.page_header(header_html)
    html = "<html><head>"
    # html += header_html
    html += '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">'
    html += "<style>"
    html += "h1 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 34pt; }\n"
    html += "h1.title { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 30pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }\n"
    html += "h2 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 28pt; }\n"
    html += "h2.title { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 24pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }\n"
    html += "h3 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; }\n"
    html += "h4 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt; }\n"
    html += "h5 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; }\n"
    html += "p { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; }\n"
    html += "table tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.simple { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.simple tr td { border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.simple tr th { border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table h4 { vertical-align: middle;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table td:first-child{ font: bold; }\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat th { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; }\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;}\n"
    html += "table.details tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 1px; }\n"
    html += "table.ci { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;}\n"
    html += "table.ci tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1pt solid black; }\n"
    html += ".ci td table, .ci td table tbody, .ci td table td { border:none; }\n" # Stops inheritence into markdown
    html += "table.note { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.note tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; }\n"
    html += "table.input_field { border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}\n"
    html += "table.input_field tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; text-align: center; vertical-align: center; padding: 5px; }\n"
    html += "table.input_field td:not(:last-child){border-right: 1px dashed}\n"
    html += "table.cl_field tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: center; padding: 2px; }\n"
    html += "table.cl_field td:first-child{ border: 1px solid black; }\n"
    html += "tr.warning { background-color: #fcf8e3; }\n"
    html += "</style>"
    html += "</head><body>"
    return html
  end

  def self.page_footer
    html = "</body></html>"
    return html
  end

  def self.title_page(title, sub_title, user)
    name = ENV['organization_title']
    image_file = ENV['organization_image_file']
    dir = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images")
    file = File.join(dir, image_file)
    time_generated = Time.now
    # Generate HTML
    html = "<br><br><div style=\"text-align: center;\"><img src=\"#{file}\" style=\"height:75px;\"></div>"
    html += "<h2 class=\"title\">#{name}</h2>"
    html += "<br>" * 10
    html += "<h1 class=\"title\">#{title}<br>#{sub_title}</h1>"
    html += "<br>" * 29
    html += "<table class=\"details\" align=\"right\"><tr><td>Run at:</td><td>#{time_generated.strftime("%Y-%b-%d, %H:%M:%S")}</td></tr><tr><td>Run by:</td><td>#{user.email}</td></tr></table>"
    html += page_break
    return html
  end

  def self.page_break
    return "<p style='page-break-after:always;'></p>"
  end

end
```

View:

```
<%= form_tag( "/study_versions/export_acrf?format=pdf", id: "preview_form_acrf", method: :post, style: "display: none;") do %>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= params[:id] %>" >
    <input type="hidden" name="table_data" value="<%= params[:table_data] %>" />
    <input type="text" name="study_version[export_type]" value="acrf" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
<% end %>
```

JS related:

```
// Study Version Editor: Annotated CRF
//

// Initialise
//
// @param [Integer] studyVersionId the id for the study version
// @return [void]
function SveAcrf(studyVersionId) {
    this.progress = new SveProgress('#aCrfPb');
    this.studyVersionId = studyVersionId;
    this.html = []; // Array for resulting HTML

    var _this = this;

    // Button handlers
    $('#study_acrf').click(function() {
        $('#soa_table thead tr th, #soa_table tbody tr td').removeClass('success'); //success
        _this.start();

    });

    $('#export_acrf').click(function() {
        // $('#table_data').val($("<div />")
        //     .append($("#soa_table").clone()).html());
        var table_data = $("<div />").append($("#soa_table").clone()).html()
        // $('#preview_form').submit();
        window.open('/study_versions/' + studyVersionId + '/export?study_version[export_type]=acrf;table_data='+table_data);
    });

}

// Start the CRF build
//
// @return [void]
SveAcrf.prototype.start = function() {
    var _this = this;
    this.clear();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/study_versions/" + this.studyVersionId,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            var forms = result.data.children;
            if (forms.length > 0) {
                _this.progress.clear(forms.length); // Set the progress total
                var table = $("<div />").append($("#soa_table").clone()).html()
                _this.html.push(table);

                for (var i=0; i<forms.length; i++) {
                    _this.html.push(_this.placeholder(i, forms[i].label)); // Create the slot for the result.
                    _this.getForm(forms[i], i);
                }
                $("#aCrfHtml").append(_this.html.join(''));
            } else {
                displayWarning("Study does not include any forms at present, nothing to display.");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){
            handleAjaxError(xhr, status, error);
        }
    });
}

// Display form
//
// @param [JS Object] form structure containing the form id and namespace
// @param [Integer] index the index of the form
// @return [void]
SveAcrf.prototype.getForm = function(form, index) {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mdrs/form_annotations",
        data: { "id": form.form_id, "namespace": form.form_namespace },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            _this.displayForm(result, index);
            setTimeout(function(){ $(".spinner_and_label_"+index).hide(); }, 500);
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){
            handleAjaxError(xhr, status, error);
        }
    });
}

// Form display
//
// @param [result] the form html
// @param [Integer] index the index of the form
// @return [void]
SveAcrf.prototype.displayForm = function(result, index) {
    this.html[index] = result; // Save the result in the correct slot
    $("#aCrfHtml").append(this.html.join('')); // Joint the array to form the whole page.
    this.progress.increment();
}

// Clear the CRF
//
// @return [void]
SveAcrf.prototype.clear = function() {
    this.progress.clear(0);
    this.html = [];
    $("#aCrfHtml").html("");
}

// Placeholder html for building the CRF
//
// @param [String] label the form label
// @return [String] the html placeholder
SveAcrf.prototype.placeholder = function(index, label) { return '<div class="row spinner_and_label_'+index+'"><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"><p><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-lg fa-fw margin-bottom"></i></p></div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-8"><p>Form: ' + label + ' will appear here ...</p></div></div>';
}

SveAcrf.prototype.openWindowWithPost = function (url, data) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.target = "_blank";
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = url;
    form.style.display = "none";

    for (var key in data) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "hidden";
        input.name = key;
        input.value = data[key];
        form.appendChild(input);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

Comment: where do you create the rows in the `PdfReport` class or in the `def export_acrf` controller method?

Comment: If you see the controller I create there the rows:
`html += params[:table_data].gsub('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success"></span>', '&#10004;') if params[:table_data].present?`
The class PDFReport is where the all PDF should be gnenerated. @FabrizioBertoglio

Comment: please include the output of `params[:table_data]` from your server log. from the picture, Education(pilot) does not have the V2-V5 cells, while the V1 cell is present and just looks like unchecked.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio sorry for the question but there is a simple way to show the log only for the params[:table_data] because my long is never ending and I'm not sure what I have to show you

Comment: I have the output here:
https://pastebin.com/ZLD8hQEj
https://pastebin.com/j78VeYpy
@FabrizioBertoglio

Answer (score 0):

As from your post

with

```
html += params[:table_data]
```

you are just adding a row for `Demographics`

```
</thead><tbody><tr><td class=\"soa-row\" id=\"2\">Demographics (Pilot)</td><td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"2\" visit_id=\"112\" id=\"36\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span></td><td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"2\" visit_id=\"113\" id=\"37\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span></td><td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"2\" visit_id=\"114\" id=\"43\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span></td><td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"2\" visit_id=\"115\" id=\"44\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span></td><td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"2\" visit_id=\"116\" id=\"45\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span></td><td class=\"soa-element\" form_id=\"2\" visit_id=\"117\" id=\"0\">"
```

if you check your `params[:table_data]` it just includes the `Demographics` row, not the `Education`

Comment: Sorry but I don't get you. When I generate my PDF I have 2 rows at the moment: 
- Demographics (Pilot)
- Education (Pilot)

But only the first row is complete with the ticks the second one is not showing the cells in the row. 

So my question is how to fix this?

Comment: @Jakub show me your params. Before you gave me an incomplete answer

Comment: My parameter https://pastebin.com/j78VeYpy 
If this is not what you ask please tell me what you need

Comment: @Jakub If you want 2 rows you need to pass in your parameters `params[:table_data] = "<table><tr>first row</tr><tr>second row</tr></table>"` while right now you are showing only one row because your params include only one row

Comment: I understood that but my tables are generated dynamically. They can have one row or many rows with many cells. How to pass in this way? @FabrizioBertoglio

Comment: @Jakub Your question does not respect the quality standards of stackoverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157903/discussion-between-jakub-and-fabrizio-bertoglio).